# Java Spring MVC partial views

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, spring-mvc

I'm learning Spring MVC at the moment and comparing it to ASP .NET MVC. Is there a way to use partial views in java (like .ascx partials in ASP .NET MVC), so i can associate it with action method of some controller and pass model data to it.

Comment: You're unlikely to find many people who know both. If you explained what you want, without reference to asp.net, it would help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with ASP .NET MVC but you might want to take a look at [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/), it's a very easy way to split up a view into several files.

[Sitemesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/) is also good for this.